# How to setup delayed jobs with multi schema based application Rails.?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, postgresql, schema, delayed-job

Can you guys guide how I will allow rake jobs:work to work for the multiple schema in both development and production environment. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set your `schema` in your `Job` class.

Assuming you have `CustomJob` class. Set your `schema` here

```
class CustomJob

  attr_accessor :object, :method_name, :args, :schema

  def initialize object, method_name, args
    @object = object
    @method_name = method_name
    @args = args
    @schema = ActiveRecord::Base.connection.schema_search_path
  end

  def perform
    object.send(method_name, *args) if object
  end

  def before(job)
    ActiveRecord::Base.connection.schema_search_path = schema
  end

  def after(job)
    ActiveRecord::Base.connection.schema_search_path = 'public'
  end

  def max_attempts
    return 2
  end

end
```

`initialize` the above Job in `Delayed::Job`

```
Delayed::Job.enqueue(CustomJob.new(object, method, args), queue: <queue>)
```

I hope this would be helpful.